# Conditional formatinfgof several date measures within one "new" card visual based on the difference between today and the respective measure

Tags: powerbi, conditional-formatting

I have a new card visual containing 3 date measures. I need to format the color of the date value of each measure based on the difference between today's date and the measure itself

For a simple card visual with a single measure ("2D LIV-C MAX DATE"), it works by using a measure which is called "diffday". Using this measure for the conditional formating works as expected.

```
diffday = DATEDIFF(TODAY(),PBS[2D LIV-C MAX DATE], DAY)
```

For a new card visual with several measures though, to avoid using single "diffday" measures for each measure, i think i could use a filed paremeter but i can't get to make it work.

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to have a diffday measure for each of your measures. Then in the `Card (new)` Format visual properties - under `Cards` you can change `Apply settings to` and select in turn each of the `Series`. And in there you can specify unique conditional formatting per series.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It does work with this solution but it is somehow quite manual. I was wondering whether there was something more efficient.

Comment: Have a look for "AdaptiveCards" visual in AppSource, it might be a good one for you. Back to your question - no, I don't think it is possible.